# Open CSV file with Apache Arrow in C++

Tags: c++, csv, apache-arrow

I'm trying to read a csv file with Apache Arrow but I can't get my head around the InputStream...
It seems the [example](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/csv.html) in their documentation is out of date.

I've tweaked a bit the example but I get "Access violation reading location" exception. Any idea what I'm doint wrong?

Thanks

My code:

```
    arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile> infile;
    infile->Open("test.csv", pool);     

    auto read_options = arrow::csv::ReadOptions::Defaults();
    auto parse_options = arrow::csv::ParseOptions::Defaults();
    auto convert_options = arrow::csv::ConvertOptions::Defaults();

    // Instantiate TableReader from input stream and options
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::csv::StreamingReader> reader;
    auto res1 = reader->Make(pool, infile, read_options, parse_options, convert_options);
    if (!res1.ok()) {
        // Handle TableReader instantiation error...
    }

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table;
    // Read table from CSV file
    
    auto res2 = reader->ReadAll(&table);
    if (!res2.ok()) {
        // Handle CSV read error
        // (for example a CSV syntax error or failed type conversion)
    }
```

Comment: why did you change st= to auto?

Comment: st is declared as a Status in their example but the functions return Results object. I just didn't bother declaring a Result object.